# How do I generate dynamic meta description and image in React using React Helmet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meta-tags, react-helmet

My program (https://rohanweb.netlify.app) is sanity API driven. It has blog post so whenever I share particular blog(using react-share), It displays default meta description and image which is inside `index.html` file. I have used React Helmet for dynamic meta tags but is doesn't seem to be working. No matter what I share, It is displaying default `meta` and when I remove that from `index.html` file it displays nothing. I have checked from https://heymeta.com . Here is sample of code for :

```
<Helmet>
<title>{singlePost.blogTitle}</title>
<link rel="canonical" href={window.location.href} />
<meta property="og:url" content={window.location.href} />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />

<meta name="twitter:card" content={singlePost.publicImg.asset.url} />

//for Title
<meta property="og:title" content={singlePost.blogTitle} />
<meta itemprop="name" content={singlePost.blogTitle} />
<meta name="twitter:title" content={singlePost.blogTitle}/>

//for Description
<meta property="og:description" content={singlePost.blogDescription} />
<meta itemprop="description" content={singlePost.blogDescription} />
<meta name="twitter:description" content={singlePost.blogDescription} />

//for Image
<meta property="og:image" content={singlePost.publicImg.asset.url} />
<meta itemprop="image" content={singlePost.publicImg.asset.url} />
<meta name="twitter:image" content={singlePost.publicImg.asset.url} />
</Helmet>
```

[Image Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V43hy.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React-helmet is not ideal for the solution required. Below is the order in which the browser handles it

1. Request a page with its path.
2. Fetch the resources for that page.
3. Load the default HTML (with meta tags...)
4. Execute JavaScript codes thereby the meta tags are updated via react-helmet.

Having your application hosted on a server, the default meta-tags are rendered as fetched. It changes only when a browser requests for a resources on a page, after which the react-helmet functions are executed.

A Better solution that I could think of would be to configure meta-tags from the server and Hydrate at the front-end.

Example Below,

```
<html>
  <head>
    __PLACEHOLDER_FOR_DYNAMIC_META_TAG__
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Read the index synchronously and replace the placeholder with meta-tag needed

```
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const fs = require("fs")

const indexFilePath= path.join(__dirname, "build/index.html")
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const myFile = fs.readFileSync(indexFilePath)
  const myMetaTag= "Meta tag details as per requirement"
  const toHydrate = myFile.replace("__PLACEHOLDER_FOR_DYNAMIC_META_TAG__", myMetaTag)
  res.send(toHydrate)
});

app.get("*", (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build/index.html"))
)
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

In your react app instead of `ReactDOM.render(<App/>, ...) use ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, ...)`

Or simply go for Next.js :)

**Updated answer for your comment below**,

```
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["keywords"].content = "Hello";
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["description"].content = "description";
```

Comment: hello there, Thanks for the help. But actually my site is static and I haven't used Node for it. Is there any other way? Next.js is good too

Comment: @thebuggybug did that solve your issue? pls do accept the answer if it helped. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Man for your help !